# Result gives undefined on the front-end in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object

I have the following `API: api_get.products.php`, which should gives me `all the products` from the `database`.

When `on the front-end` and I `parse the result`, and I try to `access the array´s object´s key properties` `one by one`, it gives me `undefined` for all the properties.

I would like to add that `same solution` worked fine when `data came from a text file`. So probably when `data comes from MySQL` there is a `different way to access` it?

The `echo` of  `$sjResponse`, however echo´s the right thing.

`[{"productCode":"200","productName":"B","productDescription":null,"quantityInStock":"198","buyPrice":"2.00","image":"img/product-image.1.png"},{"productCode":"1000","productName":"A","productDescription":null,"quantityInStock":"233","buyPrice":"1.00","image":"img/product-image.2.png"}]`

What´s wrong?

```
<?php 

    try {

            // connect to the database
            require 'connect.php';
            // create a query
            $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
            // run the query
            $bResult = $query->execute(); // result of this will return true or false
            $sajResult = json_encode( $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ); //fetch the result and turn it into a string
            //echo $sajResult;
            $sjResponse = $bResult ?  $sajResult : '{"status":"error"}'; // means if the query is true or false
            echo $sjResponse; 


    } catch (Exception $e) {

            echo "ERROR";

    }

?>
```

Here is the ajax, where everything should be fine, I just parse the response.

```
function getajProductData() {

      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if ( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {

              ajProductDataFromServer = JSON.parse( this.responseText );
              console.log( "Response:" + ajProductDataFromServer );

              if ( sessionStorage.getItem('role') === "admin" ) { 
                  //console.log( "PRODUCTS ARE EDITABLE" );
                  showProductAdmin();

              } else if ( sessionStorage.getItem('role') === "user" ) {
                  //console.log( "PRODUCTS ARE AVAILABLE FOR USER" );
                  showProduct();

              } else {
                  //console.log( "PRODUCTS AVAILABLE FOR PUBLIC" );
                  showProduct();
              }

          }
      }

      request.open( "GET", "api_get_products.php", true );
      request.send();

  }
```

And here is where I try to access the `array´s object´s properties one by one`. This also `worked fine` before when the `data came from a text file`.

```
/ DISPLAY PRODUCTS for USER / PUBLIC dinamically using a loop and then INSERT into HTML
  function showProduct() {
      lblProductList.innerHTML = "";

      for ( var i = 0; i < ajProductDataFromServer.length; i++ ) {

          var lblProduct = '<div class ="lblProduct">' + '<a href="#' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '<img src="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '" width="85%" class="lblProductImage" alt="product">' + '</a>' + '<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '<img src="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '</a>' + '<h3 class ="lblProductName">' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].name + '</h3>' + '<h3 class ="lblProductPrice">' + 'Price:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].price + '<h3 class ="lblProductQuantity">' + 'Quantity:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantity + '</h3>' + '<button class="btnBuyProduct" data-productId="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].id + '" >' + 'BUY PRODUCT' + '</button>' + '</div>';

          lblProductList.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', lblProduct );
      }

  }
```

Comment: Inspect the response text in console as well.

Comment: `console.log( "Response:" + ajProductDataFromServer );` - **don't** use `+` in logging statements this way. You are forcing string conversion here, which will give results that might easily mislead you for example for false values. If you have to output a text marker to easily identify it in console, then use `console.log("text:", value);`

Comment: Gives me what it should: `(2) [{…}, {…}]
0
:
{productCode: "200", productName: "B", productDescription: null, quantityInStock: "198", buyPrice: "2.00", …}
1
:
{productCode: "1000", productName: "A", productDescription: null, quantityInStock: "233", buyPrice: "1.00", …}
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)`

Comment: _"And here is where I try to access"_ - so you did some logging in that place as well?

Comment: `if ( sessionStorage.getItem('role') === "admin" ) { //console.log( "PRODUCTS ARE EDITABLE" ); showProductAdmin(); }`     really permission handling in javascript?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake I was trying to get the properties for `showProductAdmin()` and not for `showProduct()`since I am working with the public display yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
// DISPLAY PRODUCTS for USER / PUBLIC dinamically using a loop and then INSERT into HTML
  function showProduct() {
      lblProductList.innerHTML = "";

      for ( var i = 0; i < ajProductDataFromServer.length; i++ ) {

          var lblProduct = '<div class ="lblProduct">' + '<a href="#' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '<img src="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '" width="85%" class="lblProductImage" alt="product">' + '</a>' + '<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '<img src="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '</a>' + '<h3 class ="lblProductName">' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].productName + '</h3>' + '<h3 class ="lblProductPrice">' + 'Price:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].buyPrice + '<h3 class ="lblProductQuantity">' + 'Quantity:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantityInStock + '</h3>' + '<button class="btnBuyProduct" data-productId="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].productCode + '" >' + 'BUY PRODUCT' + '</button>' + '</div>';

          lblProductList.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', lblProduct );
      }

  }
```